# Suppose you are given arrays p[1......N] and q[1......N] both uninitialized, that is, each location may contain an arbitrary value),

Tags: c, arrays, pseudocode

Suppose you are given arrays p[1......N]  and q[1......N] both uninitialized, that is, each location may contain an arbitrary value), and a global variable count, initialized to 0. Consider the following procedures set and is_set:

```
set(i) { 
    count = count + 1; 
    q[count] = i; 
    p[i] = count; 
}

is_set(i) {
    if (p[i] ≤ 0 or p[i] > count)
        return false; 
    if (q[p[i]] ≠ i)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

A. Suppose we make the following sequence of calls:

```
 set(7); set(3); set(9);
```

After this sequence of calls, what is the value of count, and what do q[1],q[2],q[3],p[7],p[3] and p[9] contain?

B. Complete the following statement "The first count elements of __________contain values i such that set (_________________) has been called".

C. Show that if set(i) has not been called for some i, then regardless of what p[i] contains, is_set(i) will return false.

I solved the A part and B part i.e q[1]=7 q[2]=3 q[3]=9 p[7]=1 p[3]=2 p[9]=3 and B will be The first count elements of q contain values i such that set(i) has been called.

I am confused with option C; it's a little tricky.  Can someone help me to visualize it.

Comment: Since neither `p` nor `q` is passed as an argument to either of the functions, can we safely assume that they are defined as variables at file scope, possibly local to the file if defined with `static` or global if not? Which being the case, there is either an initializer for the arrays (which defines the initial values) or there is no initializer (so the elements are all zero). Do we have to allow for a perverse initializer that sets the values to outrageous, quasi-random values? (There's an element of it "doesn't matter", but enquiring minds would like to know.) Also, how big are the arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have called `set(i_1)`,`set(i_2)`,...  n times.

Now you have `count == n` and `q[1]  == i_1`, `q[2] == i_2`, ..., `q[count] == i_`*count*.

Then you call `is_set(i)` with `i` being different from all `i_`*n*.
First you access `p[i]` which still contains an arbitrary value `v`.

1. if `v <= 0` or `v > count`, `is_set(i)` return `false`
2. otherwise (1 <= v <= count) we check `q[v]` which has been assigned before with `i_`*v*. And because `i` is different from all all `i_`*n*, i is different from `i_`*v*, thus `is_set(i)` returns `false` too

Comment: That works if `set(i)` was called `N` times, but the question does not make that assumption.

Comment: @MOehm, I take the question to suppose that `count`, `p`, and `q` are modified from their (semi-)specified initial state only via the specified functions.  If one allowed them all to have arbitrary values, then the proposition in part (C) of the question would be impossible to prove.  We can certainly say that at any given point in the program's execution, `set()` has been called some non-negative number of times. This answer simply labels that number *n*, and proceeds from there.  I see no problem with any of that.

Comment: Oh, now I see my mistake: The first condition checks against `count`, not `N`. Then it all works out. Sorry for my Friday afternoon stupidity.

Answer (score 3):

(Note since this question is tagged C: This answer assumes the elements of `p` and `q` behave as if they have values that are fixed but unknown at the time execution starts. The C standard does not make this guarantee; it permits an object which has not been initialized to behave as if it has a different value each time it is used.)

Consider a call `is_set(i)` for which there was no previous `set(i)`. Assume `is_set(i)` returns true. Then `p[i] ≤ 0 or p[i] > count` must evaluate to false (or the `return false` would be executed), so `p[i]` has some value `c` that was the value of `count` in some previous call `set(x)` (although `p[i]` could have this value due to its initialize state, not due to the call `set(x)`).

That call `set(x)` set `q[c]` to `x`. Therefore `q[p[i]]` evaluates to `q[c]` and then to `x`, so `q[p[i]] ≠ i` is `x ≠ i`, which is true because there was a previous `set(x)` call but not, by our premise, a previous `set(i)` call. This causes the `return false` to be executed. That contradicts our assumption that `is_set(i)` returns true, so the assumption is false.

`is_set(i)` cannot return true when there was no previous `set(i)` call.

Answer (score 0):

p[i] is some arbitrary value, call it x.

If x is <= 0 or > count, then the first "if" of is_set triggers and the result is false.

Otherwise, there was some call to set() made when count started out equal to x - 1.  Let y be the argument to set() at that time.  Then q[x] is equal to y.  But we know that no call to set() was made with argument i, so y != i.  Hence q[x] != i.  But x is p[i], so q[p[i]] != i and the second if triggers and returns false.